# Reduce 19 columns to 5 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem. I need help!

So, I'm on Sqldeveloper/Oracle. I have 19 columns and I want to reduce it to 5 columns, but there is not always 5 fields. It's possible? For example I have this :

[image]

with this code :

```
 SELECT distinct PRO.CODPRO, 
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'LOGIST' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned1,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'LEGSEC' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned2,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'AGRICU' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned3,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'AGROAL' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned4,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'ARTAUU' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned5,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'ENTRET' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned7,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'ESPVER' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned8,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'GROEUV' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned9,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'INDCHI' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned10,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'INDLEG' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned11,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'INDLOU' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned12,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'LEGHUM' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned13,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'LOUHUM' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned14,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'LOUSEC' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned15,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'MARICU' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned16,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'SECEUV' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned17,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'TP' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned18,
        CASE RCA.CODRCA WHEN 'TRANSP' THEN RCA.CODRCA END  AS IndustriesConcerned19
        FROM PRO JOIN PRB ON PRO.MOTCLE=PRB.CODPRO JOIN RCA ON PRB.codrca=RCA.codrca where RCA.typrca='UTI' AND RCA.CODRCA<>'LEGSEC' AND RCA.CODRCA<>'LOUSEC' AND RCA.CODRCA<>'LEGHUM' AND RCA.CODRCA<>'LOUHUM';
```

I want this with 5 columns like this

[image]

Do you have a solution?

Comment: you always want the same 5 columns?

Comment: use coalesce function and output 5 columns

Comment: What version of Oracle Database are you using?

Comment: I would be against creation of such case statements and use a look up table which would contain the values you are comparing in the case statement

Comment: - Yes I would like the same 5 columns
- Coalesce would be good I think (I have never used it) but uses several columns from the same table
- My version of Oracle Database is Version  19.2.1.247
- And I cannot create a new table unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for a the simple [`PIVOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) feature.

The only difference is you do not want to `pivot` on the column *value*, but possible on the *keyword order*.

Here the query to pivot on the *alphabetical order* of the keywords.

*Note, that the first two subqueries produce only the simplified data* as follows:

```
CODPRO  CODRCA
------- ------
400JE   LOGIST
400JE   INDLEG
50EFJ10 TP    
50EFJ10 ESPVER
50EFJ10 AGRICU
50EFJ10 INDLEG
50EFJ10 LOGIST
```

Query calculates first the row number using the order of the `CODRCA` and the `pivot` on it:

```
with PRO as (
select '400JE' CODPRO from dual union all
select '50EFJ10' CODPRO from dual),
RCA as (
select '400JE' CODPRO, 'LOGIST' CODRCA from dual union all
select '400JE' CODPRO, 'INDLEG' CODRCA from dual union all
select '50EFJ10' CODPRO, 'TP' CODRCA from dual union all
select '50EFJ10' CODPRO, 'ESPVER' CODRCA from dual union all
select '50EFJ10' CODPRO, 'AGRICU' CODRCA from dual union all
select '50EFJ10' CODPRO, 'INDLEG' CODRCA from dual union all
select '50EFJ10' CODPRO, 'LOGIST' CODRCA from dual),
rn as (
select PRO.CODPRO,RCA.CODRCA,
row_number() over (partition by PRO.CODPRO order by RCA.CODRCA) as rn
from PRO
join RCA on PRO.CODPRO = RCA.CODPRO)
select *
from rn
pivot (max(CODRCA)  CODRCA for (rn) in
(1 as "C1",
 2 as "C2",
 3 as "C3",
 4 as "C4",
 5 as "C5"))
```

result

```
CODPRO  C1_COD C2_COD C3_COD C4_COD C5_COD
------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
400JE   INDLEG LOGIST                     
50EFJ10 AGRICU ESPVER INDLEG LOGIST TP
```

If you prefer other *sorting logik* adapt as required.
Also adapt if you need different column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like the one below to concatenate the distinct list of **CODRCA** values into a comma delimited list, then split the list into 5 different columns. You can also add ordering to the LISTAGG if you so desire.

```sql
select codpro,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,1) as IndustriesConcerned1,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,2) as IndustriesConcerned2,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,3) as IndustriesConcerned3,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,4) as IndustriesConcerned4,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,5) as IndustriesConcerned5
 from (
  SELECT CODPRO, LISTAGG (CODRCA, ',') as codrca_list
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PRO.CODPRO, RCA.CODRCA
            FROM PRO
                 JOIN PRB ON PRO.MOTCLE = PRB.CODPRO
                 JOIN RCA ON PRB.codrca = RCA.codrca
           WHERE     RCA.typrca = 'UTI'
                 AND RCA.CODRCA <> 'LEGSEC'
                 AND RCA.CODRCA <> 'LOUSEC'
                 AND RCA.CODRCA <> 'LEGHUM'
                 AND RCA.CODRCA <> 'LOUHUM')
GROUP BY codpro);
```

Comment: Your code is exact thank you so much! But I have an code and I don't say how to integrate your code with mine

Comment: Without a clearer description of what your existing code is, I can not help you. If you need assistance with that, it should be asked in a separate question since this query answers the question that was asked.