# Integrate 2 codes in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm in Sqldeveloper / Oracle
I have a problem I want integrate 2 codes can we help me ?
I want this code :

```
`select codpro,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,1) as IndustriesConcerned1,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,2) as IndustriesConcerned2,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,3) as IndustriesConcerned3,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,4) as IndustriesConcerned4,
       regexp_substr(codrca_list, '[^,]+',1,5) as IndustriesConcerned5
 from (
  SELECT CODPRO, LISTAGG (CODRCA, ',') as codrca_list
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT PRO.CODPRO, RCA.CODRCA
            FROM PRO
                 JOIN PRB ON PRO.MOTCLE = PRB.CODPRO
                 JOIN RCA ON PRB.codrca = RCA.codrca
           WHERE     RCA.typrca = 'UTI'
                 AND RCA.CODRCA <> 'LEGSEC'
                 AND RCA.CODRCA <> 'LOUSEC'
                 AND RCA.CODRCA <> 'LEGHUM'
                 AND RCA.CODRCA <> 'LOUHUM')
GROUP BY codpro);`
```

In this code :

```
`SELECT 
    PRO.CODPRO as SKU,
    PRO.MOTCLE AS PARENTPRODUCTSKU,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FAM.CODEFAM = PRO.FAMPRO THEN FAM.LIBFAM END) AS MarketNomLab1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FAM.CODESFA = PRO.SFAPRO THEN FAM.LIBFAM END) AS MarketNomLab2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN FAM.CODESSF = PRO.SSFPRO THEN FAM.LIBFAM END) AS MarketNomLab3,
    PRO.CODPRO AS ProductName,
    AA_PRODUIT.NBRE_00 AS QuantityITS,
    AA_PRODUIT.NBRE_01 AS QuantityITC,
    PRO.GENCOD AS "GTI/EAN",
    AA_PRODUIT.GENCOD_00 AS "GTIN/EAN Sachet",
    AA_PRODUIT.GENCOD_01 AS "GTIN/EAN Carton",
    PRO.CODZN7 AS CountryOrigin,
    PRO.CODUNI AS TypeOfPkgList,
    PRO.CODZN10 AS "EPI CLASS",
    PRO.CODDOU AS CustomsCode,
    PRO.LONGUE AS DepthOTC,
    PRO.HAUTE AS HeightOTC,
    PRO.VOLUME AS VolumeOTC,
    PRO.POIDS AS WeightOTC,
    PRO.LARGE AS WidthOTC,
    PRO.DESIGN5||PRO.DESIGN6 AS ProductCommArg1
FROM PRO 
JOIN PRB ON PRO.CODPRO = PRB.CODPRO 
JOIN FAM ON PRB.CODSOC = FAM.CODSOC 
JOIN AA_PRODUIT ON PRO.CODPRO=AA_PRODUIT.CODPRO
WHERE fam.typtie='PRO' AND (FAM.CODEFAM = PRO.FAMPRO OR FAM.CODESFA = PRO.SFAPRO OR FAM.CODESSF = PRO.SSFPRO)
GROUP BY PRO.CODPRO, PRO.MOTCLE, PRO.CODPRO, AA_PRODUIT.NBRE_00, AA_PRODUIT.NBRE_01,PRO.GENCOD, AA_PRODUIT.GENCOD_00, AA_PRODUIT.GENCOD_01, PRO.CODZN7, PRO.CODUNI, PRO.CODZN10, PRO.CODDOU, PRO.LONGUE, PRO.HAUTE, PRO.VOLUME,PRO.POIDS, PRO.LARGE, PRO.DESIGN5||PRO.DESIGN6;`
```

I would like to integrate this two example :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mesZp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ6Eg.png)

Do you have a solution ?
Cause I don't know how to do it I thank you in advance

Comment: Where are you trying to merge the query?  Have you tried a WITH clause?

Comment: The first query is the aswer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64555401/4808122) question, but it seems to be unrelated with the second query...

Comment: Providing sample data and expected result would help